# MIT and MS-LPL license compatibility options

Tags: mit, license-compatibility, ms-pl, isc

My project is `MIT` licensed and 3rd party code is all either `ISC` or `MIT` licensed which are both compatible licenses.

I maintain project code licenses [per file](https://softwarefreedom.org/resources/2012/ManagingCopyrightInformation.html#maintaining-file-scope-copyright-notices), that is each source includes a license comment on top of a file, each file is a subject to it's own Copyright and license notices.

However entry project as a whole is `MIT` because 3rd party (non `MIT`) code is sublicensed.

Problem now is that I want to include another 3rd party code (a single file) which is `MS-LPL` licensed.

`MS-LPL` [Microsoft Limited Public License](https://www.openhub.net/licenses/mslpl) is not OSI approved because of a restriction which state that the `MS-LPL` licensed software/code is permitted to run only on Microsoft Windows OS:

> 4. (F) Platform Limitation- The licenses granted in sections 2(A) & 2(B) extend only to the software or derivative works that you create
>    that run on a Microsoft Windows operating system product

I have no problem with that because the software (project) as a whole is not cross platform and can run only on Windows anyway.

Another issue with `MS-MPL` is that it does not permit sublicensing:

> (D) If you distribute any portion of the software in source code form,
> you may do so only under this license by including a complete copy of
> this license with your distribution.

I'm considering between 2 options and I'm not sure whether either one or both options are valid thing to do to keep my project under single license as a whole:

1. Include `MS-LPL` licensed file into project, and put license and Copyright comment into this file just like every other file in the project does.
2. Relicense entry project (my own work) as `MS-LPL` and let 3rd party code stay as it is, `MIT` and `ISC` licensed.

Problem with first option is that entry project can't be published as `MIT` licensed because it contains a `MS-LPL` licensed file which can't be sublicensed and does permit porting code to other systems.

Second option looks less problematic but problem is again that entry project can't be `MS-LPL` licensed because it would contain `MIT` code which opposes restrictions introduced by `MS-LPL` license

I could be easily wrong on these 2 options, maybe there are some other options I should consider?